# Unable to translate notice in mod message for user without verified email

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, localization, email-verification

The following notice doesn't have source string to translate on mod message page:

> This user does not have a verified email address so this message will only be seen on {site name}.

> [image]

Link for test for staff: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/message/create/-1